# NPM commands return error: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: json, npm

... and I *know* that my json is perfectly valid json.
The problem started when I added some dev dependencies to the package.json, but it seems to be getting tripped up on the first lines. I've verified and cleaned the cache, updated npm, and I've combed through the file and the posts on this problem for a while, but cannot figure out what's going on. I've also tried some suggestions I saw on here, like changing all the " characters to ' characters. Nada.

My package.json is below, as well as the full error message when I run a command:

```
{
  "name": "Outlook Beaty",
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "description": "A custom experience enhancer for Outlook.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/team5-devs/js-outlook-plugin/"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "app-to-debug": "outlook",
    "app-type-to-debug": "desktop",
    "dev-server-port": 3000
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@types/find-process": "1.2.0",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.108",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.14",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-office-addins": "^1.0.19",
    "find-process": "^1.4.3",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "generator-office": "^1.7.8",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.4",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.0.13",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^3.0.34",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.5.5",
    "office-addin-lint": "^1.0.26",
    "office-addin-manifest": "1.5.7",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.0.12",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "travis-ci": "^2.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    "yo": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --mode production --https false",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development --https false",
    "build-dev": "webpack --mode development --https false && echo . && echo . && echo . && echo Please use 'build:dev' instead of 'build-dev'.",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "test": "jasmine",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  }
}
```

`npm install`

```
npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "Outlook Beaty",
npm ERR! JSON.parse "versio'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I'm running Gitbash on Windows 10, but I tried to make sure that there are no Windows-specific characters. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: I've added a missing comma on line 47 (near dependency yo) and it seems to install for me locally. Could you verify and let me know if that helps?

Comment: It should solve your question because if I remove it, I get the error you're getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem might be simpler than you overlooked?

I see on line (near yo dependency) you're missing a comma:

```
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    "yo": "^3.1.1"
```

I suggest you add a comma, then try to run `npm install` again?

```
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "yo": "^3.1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you solved my problem! It's still warning me that my project name is invalid, and a bunch of other fields are missing like description and license. Do you have any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Those are the usual npm warnings, those fields are not important for the project itself, so it's safe to ignore them. I'm not sure where you downloaded the project from ( I guess it's from your client/company ) but whoever made the project didn't specify the "description", and the "license" fields. You can safely ignore those warnings, or you can even add those fields yourself, those are just metadata used by the publishing of packages to open source, etc. They are softly required. If you decide to add them, just check with your company at what exact value they should have.